# can't organise my data in my tableau

Tags: php, angularjs

I'm using php and Angular JS and this is my code :

```
 <table  class="table table-bordered">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th><Bold>Participation fille-société</Bold></th>
                            <th><Bold>Secteur d'activité</Bold></th>
                            <th><Bold>Date d'acquisition</Bold></th>
                            <th><Bold>Prix d'acquisition</Bold></th>
                            <th><Bold>Tri actualisé</Bold></th>
                            <th><Bold>Type d'operation</Bold></th>
                            <th><Bold>Participations meres</Bold></th>
                            <th><Bold>Action<Bold></th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        </tbody>
                        <tr >
                            <td><Bold><a href="consultationPFS.php?id_participationfilleS={{ps.id_participationfilleS}}">{{ps.nomParticipationFilleS}}</Bold></td>
                            <td><Bold>{{ps.secteurActivite}}</Bold></td>
                            <td><Bold>{{ps.date_aquisition}}</Bold></td>
                            <td><Bold>{{ps.Prix_acquisition}}</Bold></td>
                            <td><Bold>{{ps.tri_actualise}}</Bold></td>
                            <td><Bold>{{ps.tri_actualise}}</Bold></td>
                            <td  ng-repeat="ac in DataPmers"><Bold>{{ac.nom_participation}} {{ac.pourcentage}}%</Bold></td>
                            <td><a type="submit" class="edit-row" href="UpdatePFS.php?id_participationfilleS={{ps.id_participationfilleS}}" title="Modifier" ><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a> |  <a type="submit" class="delet-row" title="Supprimer" ng-click="supp(ps)"><i class="fa fa-trash"</i></button></a> | <a type="submit" class="edit-row" href="EtatPFS.php?id_participationfilleS={{ps.id_participationfilleS}}" title="Modifier" ><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a></td>

                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table><div class="box-footer clearfix">
```

And the result like in the picture below :

[image]

As u can see in Participations meres it give me only one data and other line of data in other column

How can I get all data of participation mere in the same column ?

Comment: Don't repeat the td node. Repeat the Bold node instead.

Comment: cant understund how can i do this Peter

Comment: Put ng-repeat on the Bold node, not the td.

Comment: yes peter thinks for your answer its correct but still only one problem that it give me all data in the same line

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you - new row of the table for each DataPmers?

```
<table  class="table table-bordered">
                 <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th><Bold>Participation fille-société</Bold></th>
                        <th><Bold>Secteur d'activité</Bold></th>
                        <th><Bold>Date d'acquisition</Bold></th>
                        <th><Bold>Prix d'acquisition</Bold></th>
                        <th><Bold>Tri actualisé</Bold></th>
                        <th><Bold>Type d'operation</Bold></th>
                        <th><Bold>Participations meres</Bold></th>
                        <th><Bold>Action<Bold></th>
                    </tr>
                 </thead>
                 </tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="ac in DataPmers">
                        <td><Bold><a href="consultationPFS.php?id_participationfilleS={{ps.id_participationfilleS}}">{{ps.nomParticipationFilleS}}</Bold></td>
                        <td><Bold>{{ps.secteurActivite}}</Bold></td>
                        <td><Bold>{{ps.date_aquisition}}</Bold></td>
                        <td><Bold>{{ps.Prix_acquisition}}</Bold></td>
                        <td><Bold>{{ps.tri_actualise}}</Bold></td>
                        <td><Bold>{{ps.tri_actualise}}</Bold></td>
                        <td><Bold>{{ac.nom_participation}} {{ac.pourcentage}}%</Bold></td>
                        <td><a type="submit" class="edit-row" href="UpdatePFS.php?id_participationfilleS={{ps.id_participationfilleS}}" title="Modifier" ><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a> |  <a type="submit" class="delet-row" title="Supprimer" ng-click="supp(ps)"><i class="fa fa-trash"</i></button></a> | <a type="submit" class="edit-row" href="EtatPFS.php?id_participationfilleS={{ps.id_participationfilleS}}" title="Modifier" ><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a></td>

                    </tr>
                 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thinks for your answer but it give me 2 line with the same data